# Wireguard not working on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, wireguard

I have wireguard config file which i successfully using on my android phone, but it is not working on my laptop. it connects but doesn't work.
How can i fix it? Please, help me.

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey  = private_content
Address = 10.20.200.133/24
MTU = 1342

DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey   = private_content
AllowedIPs  = 10.20.200.1/32, 78.155.203.242/32, 78.155.203.243/32, 78.155.203.244/32, 78.155.203.245/32
Endpoint    = 13.48.115.47:20300
```

Comment: looks OK - what operating system are you running on your laptop? how are you bringing up the wireguard connection?

Comment: i `ve got linux mint 21.2 (basically ubuntu 22/04). sudo wg-quick up wg0 - standard way to connect.
by the way, i have another wg config, which works fine.

Comment: `i have another wg config, which works fine` so, use that ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: this is for different servers

Comment: what differences are there between the two servers and the two files?

Answer (score 0):

Pls check or double check if

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <is yours **local machine** private key>
```

and

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = <is the public key of your **remote server**>
```

then try to remove the MTU, wireguard make a default mtu that generally works fine.